# Set Default Directory for Lotus Notes File Upload Control

Tags: c#, file-upload, lotus-notes

I have a lotus notes web form in which computer-illiterate customers will use to attach Excel files and submit them to our company.  I am using a Lotus Notes File Upload Control to allow them to do this, however, I need to default this File Upload Control to a certain directory location.  I have already created a C# application the customers will be using, which places all of these excel files in a certain directory location, hence the reason I need to focus this File Upload Control.  Unfortunately, some of the customers are computer challenged enough to not know how to navigate to these files on their own.  Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would investigate using the Notes API to have the C# program handle the upload without involving the browser client use of the file upload control. I don't know enough Java to be sure, but perhaps that might also be an option -- basically writing your own custom upload control that only asks the user for the filename.

You may also be seriously underestimating the ability of the users to follow directions. If your page identifies which directory the file will be found in, I expect most users will be able to follow the directions and upload from the correct directory.

So, I'm sure that accomplishing what you want to accomplish is possible in Notes, just not as simply as adding a default directory to the File Upload Control.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the users will be visiting a web page with the File Upload control, yes?  If I'm misunderstanding please let me know and I'll delete this answer.

The simple answer is it isn't possible.  The problem is that the browser can't know anything about the file structure of the clients that visit the site, so a "default path" property doesn't really make sense.  It would likely only work in very specific environments (which is maybe true in your case, but not across the web in general)

Comment: Yes it would be a web page they would be visiting.  I feared your answer would be the correct one.